# Swift - Realm is on main thread for some reason

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So i am refactoring some code and i have thread safety issues with realm.

I have 2 layers, the first is Local storage:

```
class LocalStorage {

  static private var db: RealmDB = RealmDB.sharedInstance

  static func updateTest(_ object: [Object], async: Bool = true, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if async {
        db.insertAsynctTest(object, success: {
            success()
        }) {
            failure()
        }
    } else {
        db.insertTest(object, success: {
            success()
        }) {
            failure()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The second is the singltone realm:

```
class RealmDB {

// create OR update

static let sharedInstance = RealmDB()

var realm: Realm?

init() {
    do {
        self.realm = try Realm()

    } catch {
        handleError(error)
    }
}

func insertAsynctTest(_ objects: [Object], success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").async {
        autoreleasepool {
            if let realmDB = self.realm {
                do {
                    try realmDB.write {
                        for object in objects {
                            realmDB.add(object, update: .modified)
                        }
                        success()
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    failure()
                }
            }
            failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Yet every time i am using the local storage - realm i am crushing on "Realm accessed from incorrect thread"

I have tried to init the singletone on the same thread ("com.example.myApp.bg") yet i still crush.
Would like to understand what is happening in the threads there.

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but are you aware that the `failure` closure is always executed, even in case of success? You need to put that inside an `else` block after the `if let`. Also, what's `db.insertTest`? Is that the problematic question or is it `insertAsynctTest`? Which exact line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: @DávidPásztor the write one

Comment: Try putting the DispatchQueue.async inside the try realm.write block.

Comment: @rs7 that does not sound like what he wants at all

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Realm instance in different threads. Each thread require own instance.

> Sharing Realm instances across threads is not supported. Realm instances accessing the same Realm file must also all use the same Realm.Configuration.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading

Try this:

```
   DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").async {
    autoreleasepool {
        if let realmDB = try? Realm() {
            do {
                try realmDB.write {
                    for object in objects {
                        realmDB.add(object, update: .modified)
                    }
                    success()
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                failure()
            }
        }
        failure()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is quite clear.

```
init() {
    do {
        self.realm = try Realm() // <-- runs on UI thread
```

then

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {    
    autoreleasepool {
        if let realmDB = self.realm { // <-- runs on background thread
```

Realm instances are thread-confined, so you cannot do this. Just like how you cannot touch UI stuff on a background thread, it is the exact same concept.

Solution: call `try Realm()` for the given thread where you are trying to use it.

Comment: Don't both your snippets run on the main thread?

Comment: I don't think so, shouldn't `async` put it on background? Well either way, if you are on a background thread, use autoreleasepool. Feel free to edit to a DispatchQueue that is not the main.

Comment: It depends on what queue async is called on, in your case, you're calling it on `main` so async will dispatch the block on the main queue which is exceptional in that it only has one dedicated thread.  Try this: `DispatchQueue.main.async { print("Is main thread: ", Thread.isMainThread)}`.  I'm confused why I'm seeing `autoreleasepool` in docs as well.  It shouldn't be necessary when using ARC.

Comment: @ScottyBlades If the dispatch queue belongs to a background thread pool, then without the autoreleasepool, the instances can live too long, and you can end up with too many versions, increasing file size significantly

Comment: With arc the ending of the scope decrements the retain count at the conclusion of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't creating the `Realm` instance on the same thread as where you are accessing it from. You need to dispatch the instantiation of the instance to your dedicated queue as well as the accessing.

```
init() {
    do {
        DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.myApp.bg").sync {
            self.realm = try Realm()
        }
    } catch {
        handleError(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: A queue is not a thread.